# Limit storage usage of an app

Tags: storage

How to limit how much space an app can take ?

Facebook, for example... Keeps caching useless stuff on the background

Dont care if it breaks functionality

Have xPosed if needed

Edit:

Somehow, android tells the apps when there's no space left

Maybe someone can clone this functionality to fool the app

Comment: I am rooted. Any suggestions for that case ? I tried many times FB lite. It's horrible.

Comment: I have not done this with FB but this comes to mind http://www.droidviews.com/increase-file-size-limit-whatsapp/

Comment: Not only that. I noticed that power consumption grows with the size of the internal data used by the App (any large app).